# How to print date 9999-99-99 in xmlgregoriancalendar?

Tags: java, xmlgregoriancalendar

Need to print the date exactly as "9999-99-99" using xmlgregoriancalendar type.
When i pass "9999-99-99" i get wrong output: 10007-07-08. How do i get output exactly as 9999-99-99

```
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;

public class XMLGregorianCalendar {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    /* Create Date Object */
    //Date date = new Date();

      javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = null;
      //GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(2001,12,12);
      GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(9999,99,99);
      // gc.setTime(date);

        try{
          xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
        }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("XMLGregorianCalendar :- " + xmlDate);

      } 

}
```

Comment: but why? ..... 99 is not a valid month nor a valid day in any month. Don't use the calendar, just string formatting

Comment: or use 12-31 as month-day for any type of "max" date

Comment: You can’t. It’s not a valid date, so `XMLGregorianCalendar` is not going to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

### Don’t

The `XMLGregorianCalendar` class was for dates and/or times for XML documents. Assuming that this was also your purpose, you must not put `9999-99-99` there. It’s not a valid date according to XML rules. Quoting *XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition*, appendix D *ISO 8601 Date and Time Formats*:

> - M -- represents a digit used in the time element "month". The two digits in a MM format can have values from 1 to 12.
> - D -- represents a digit used in the time element "day". The two digits in a DD format can have values from 1 to 28 if the month value
>     equals 2, 1 to 29 if the month value equals 2 and the year is a leap
>     year, 1 to 30 if the month value equals 4, 6, 9 or 11, and 1 to 31 if
>     the month value equals 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10 or 12.

I have taken it out of context, but I think that we should understand that dates in XML documents need to be valid dates. 9999-99-99 is not a valid date since there is no month 99 and no month has 99 days in it.

If you wanted `9999-99-99` for something else than an XML document, I don’t think you should be using `XMLGregorianCalendar` at all. Without context I dare not suggest alternatives.

**java.time** I said “*was* … for XML documents”. Dates and times in XML documents are inspired from ISO 8601 formats and close enough that we usually can use the classes from java.time, the modern Java date and time API rather than `XMLGregorianCalendar` for them and still get the correct syntax from the `toString` methods of those classes. So also for valid dates consider using the modern `LocalDate` from java.time rather than the old `XMLGregorianCalendar`.

### You cannot

`XMLGregorianCalendar` imposes the restriction of a valid date, so cannot print `9999-99-99`.

What happened in your code was that `GregorianCalendar` tacitly and confusingly modified the date into a valid one. Try for example:

```
    GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(9999,99,99);
    System.out.println(gc.getTime());
```

On my computer I got:

> Sun Jul 08 00:00:00 CEST 10007

When given invalid month and day of month, `GregorianCalendar` just keeps counting months and days into the following years. Since 99 months is a little more than 8 years, we end up more than 8 years after January 9999, and a further 3 months because of the 99 days. This was then the date that you passed to your `XMLGregorianCalendar`, which explains the output you got.

### Links

- [*XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes Second Edition*, appendix D *ISO 8601 Date and Time Formats*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats)
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.