# How to set time "0000-00-00 00:00:00" to LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, date, datetime

To write test I need to set `LocalDateTime`to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.
When I try to set it using formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime.parse("0000-00-00 00:00:00", formatter)
```

it throws an exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '0000-00-00 00:00:00' could not be parsed: Invalid value for YearOfEra (valid values 1 - 999999999/1000000000): 0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: This is not a valid date, so you can't set it. What is the code have to test?

Comment: I need this for legacy code which I can't change.

Comment: Then show the code under test, maybe we can show you an other way

Comment: Somehow similar: [How to print date 9999-99-99 in xmlgregoriancalendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57852833/how-to-print-date-9999-99-99-in-xmlgregoriancalendar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to set day 0 of month 0 of year 0. So there're 3 errors there:

- There's no day 0 in any month. Days always starts in 1
- There's no month 0 in any year. Months always starts in 1
- [There's no year 0 in the Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero). That's the error you're getting (`Invalid value for YearOfEra`). You should set a year greater than 0

Comment: Two thirds correct. There is a year 0 in [the proleptic Gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar). `LocalDateTIme` and the other classes from java.time use this calendar. Only there is no year 0 *in the default era* (common era or anno dominum).

Comment: Wrong case, it’s *anno domini*, sorry.